Where can I find physics books affordable costs or can I copy PDFs online?
Can I copy pdf online of physics books to study and as hard copy at low price or any legal issues

I'm closing this question (v2) as it seems more about copyrights and costs than physics.

They charge a lot because libraries at universities and other institutions, or individuals for free from a grant,  are willing to pay any price just to have teh book and show their status. So it is a scam and a failure of capitalism. Then for the poor student the price of books is unreachable, or that of a single scientific articles if you buy them from a journal.
